# Issue with Soft State in OData Service Not Triggering Operation_Start

Tags: odata, sapui5, abap

I'm currently facing an interesting issue with the implementation of soft state in an OData service within a specific customer system. In all other systems, the soft state functionality operates as expected, and I don't encounter any problems. However, in this particular customer system, I've noticed that the Operation_Start method is not being triggered, and as a result, I'm unable to change the value of **mv_is_softstate**.

An interesting observation is that when I use this OData service in conjunction with a UI5 application and set the useBatch status to false for the OData model, the soft state starts working correctly.

Has anyone else faced a similar issue with soft state in OData services?

Some Components Versions:

```
SAP_ABA     75H 0002    Cross-Application Component
SAP_BASIS   757 0002    SAP Basis Component
SAP_GWFND   757 0002    SAP Gateway Foundation
```

Here are some screenshots:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved. I wanted to post an answer here for future developers who might spend time trying to find a solution to this annoying issue. In short, the issue was related to the 'System Alias'.

In my case, the System Alias was set to 'LOCAL_TGW' by the basis team some time ago. Then, while I was debugging, I found the following method in the background of the SAP request process. It seems that if this 'rv_is_co_deployment' is initial, in the subsequent steps the system struggles to handle batch request headers correctly and can't process the request in the soft state mode. After updating the System Alias to 'LOCAL', everything is working correctly now.

[image]

[image]